# How to fix GWT upload item in fire fox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, gwt, smartgwt

i am wondering if there is any way to fix the look of the GWT upload item on fire fox
it looks like this:
[image: GWT upload item]

can any one please provide any help ?
thanx .

Comment: it looks like a height issue. Set a larger height to the `<input type="file">` tag. But it is impossible to style the 'Browse' button and 'No file selected' text since that's just how Firefox has implemented `<input type="file">`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps You could look at the css style with firebug and overide by adding "!important" in your css file